# NodeJS 14: Using a SSL CA Bundle

Tags: node.js, typescript, ssl, ca

I'm currently trying to use a CA Bundle with NodeJS 14.0.  I've been using Namecheap's [article](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9705/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nodejs#import) as a guide the implement this feature.  I'm currently stuck on a few things:

1. For the `ca` parameter for https.createServer(), what file formats are allowed to be passed in?
2. How do I check that a CA bundle is actually being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For the ca parameter for https.createServer(), what file formats are allowed to be passed in?

From [NodeJS `tls.createSecureContext`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options):

> Any string or Buffer can contain multiple PEM CAs concatenated together

Though, in general NodeJS uses PEM format.

## How do I check that a CA bundle is actually being used?

You can use a certificate not signed by your CA, e.g. a self-signed certificate.

Comment: So is `tls.createSecureContext()` called in the background by `https.createServer()` or does the user have to call the function?  If the latter, then what's the point of the Namecheap article?

Comment: @JosephWoolf, `tls.createSecureContext()` is called in the background

Comment: Got it.  Now how exactly does not using a certificate signed by the CA allow you check whether the CA bundle is actually being used?

Comment: Well if it errors out, you know that the bundle was referenced, although you normally don't need to check if it actually works or not.

Comment: For this case, I would need to check.  Now, how can this be done?

Comment: The easiest method would be to specify an invalid (e.g. self-signed) certificate and see if an error occurs - although this method basically checks nodejs internal problems as a specified bundle should always be used.

Comment: And by invalid self-signed certificate, we're talking about supplying a different certificate from the root certificate found in the CA bundle?  So if I do this on Chrome, I would get a NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALI?  If this is wrong. then I'm very confused

Comment: Yes, The "test" is mostly seeing if it breaks on invalid input

Answer (score 0):

One point, possibly more subtle than you wanted: nodejs `tls.createSecureContext` internally calls OpenSSL `PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX` which actually accepts **three PEM formats** (or any sequence of those three formats, since nodejs loops). For two of them the base64/64cpl blob contains (exactly) an X.509 certificate, as respecified in [rfc7468 sec 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-5), with either preferred label "CERTIFICATE" or deprecated label "X509 CERTIFICATE". In addition OpenSSL accepts a format of its own with label "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE" where the blob contains an X.509 certificate *plus* additional (ASN.1) data defined by OpenSSL; see e.g. the man page for `d2i_X509_AUX` [online here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/d2i_X509_AUX.html). OpenSSL doesn't use this additional data for much, and of course nothing else uses it at all, so it's rare.

And to avoid confusion it might be worth noting that *all* OpenSSL `PEM_read_` routines, including this one, skip any 'comment' data while searching for the PEM data, so actually a file/buffer that contains garbage, then a PEM cert, then more garbage, then another PEM cert, etc. will work the same as if it contained only the PEM certs.